# Winforms in Excel add-in won't update

Tags: c#, excel

I am developing an Excel Add-In in C# in VS2015. When I click a button, let's say `btnShowData`,  I use the text of a textbox `textBox1` and I send this text to a method. When I change the text in the textbox, when clicking `btnShowData`, it always take the default value of the `textBox1`.

```
private void btnShowData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      MessageBox.Show(this.textBox1.Text);
      GetAS400Data(textBox1.Text);
}
```

`textBox1` is a TextBox in a WinForm I launch.

Comment: can you show the method of `GetAS400Data` please..?

Comment: ...also whats the value of.. texBox1.text... at the point where the GetAS400Data is called.....lets start from there...is it the new data or the defult...?...

Comment: When I call `GetAS400Data`, I put a breakpoint on the first line of the method to inspect the string input which is the value of the textbox. Whatever I put in this textbox it is always the same value.